# configure D-link Dir-300

Tags: macos, networking, router

I have a D-link DIR-300 router, but I am having problems configuring it on my network because I do not know what is my network type.

So in order to connect to my network through mac, I need to enter a manual IP address given by my ISP, and then go to the terminal and run an ssh command, with the command:

```
ssh user@server
```

which then asks me for the password of my account.

I have tried PPPoE configurations, but that did not work either, any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Who is your ISP?  I'm doubtful that you need to enter PPPoE settings if your ISP has given you manual/static ip addresses.

Comment: It sounds like your network is static IP network connection to your ISP because they gave an IP address, but further information is required.